# How to use "nmake" command in Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, makefile

I would like to run a batch file below with VisualStudio2017 developer's command prompt.

```
Set PATH=c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin;%PATH%
Set INCLUDE=c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include;c:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Include;%INCLUDE%
Set LIB=c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\lib;c:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Lib;%LIB%
Set COMSPEC=cmd.exe
rem nmake -f Makefile.msvc clean
nmake -f Makefile.msvc
```

But, my command prompt say that "nmake is not recognized as internal-command, external-command, operatable-program or batch-file." in JAPANESE.(see attatched file)
[image]

Please tell me that how to use "nmake" command with VisualStudio2017.

Comment: It's been a couple years since I've used nmake, but IIRC, you use `/` to denote a command-line switch with most Microsoft products, not `-`...so try `nmake /f Makefile.msvc`